# How to dismiss a dialog on button click? Button is in a layout which is set to the dialog using setContentView

Tags: android

I derived a dialog from Dialog of android. And set a layout to the dialog using **`setContentView()`**. There is button in my layout and i need to dismiss the dialog on that button click. Now i put a Toast on the button click and working fine. How to do this? Following is the code i have written so far.

```
public class ErrorAlertDialog extends Dialog {

private TextView _errormessagetitle, _errormessagedescription;
private String _title, _description;

public BSFErrorAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String description) {
    super(context);

    _title = title;
    _description = description;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.bsfalerterror);

    final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnerrordialogok);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           Toast.makeText(getContext(), "button1 click",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
    _errormessagetitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bsftxterrorheading);
    _errormessagetitle.setText(_title);

    _errormessagedescription = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bsftxterrormessage);
    _errormessagedescription.setText(_description);
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write like this:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          // Toast.makeText(getContext(), "button1 click",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ErrorAlertDialog.this.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getDialog().dismiss(); //or getDialog().cancel();
```

use that in replace of toast